# $3$ immiscible liquids in a communicating vessel

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

> We have $3$ immiscible liquids in a communicating vessel.
>   [image]
>
> I should determine which liquid has the smallest density.

I think it's liquid $1$, but I cannot give an adequate explanation. Does the first liquid have the smallest density and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: 3 liquids]

In order to figure out which of the liquids has the lowest density, determine the *hydrostatic pressure* according to Pascal's Law, at the intersection of the red line and the tubes $1$, $2$ and $3$.

Note that the pressure at these points will be equal, otherwise liquid would be flowing from one tube to another. These equalities allow determining which liquid has the lowest density.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I got that $xh_1=yh_2=zh_3$ where $x, y, z$ are the corresponding densities. I am not sure I can continue it from here. What to do next?

Comment: That's correct. It would be clearer to call them $d_1$, $d_2$ and $d_3$ though.

Comment: Okay. But what does this mean?

Comment: If $xh_1=yh_2$, what does it say about $x$ and $y$?

Comment: How to finish from here? We don't know the exact highs to calculate the densities.

Comment: You know that $h_2 > h_1$.

Comment: So $x>y$, right?

Comment: Correct. That's how it works.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much! I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome.